# Open function C "file not found" on Xcode but terminal works

Tags: c, xcode, xcode6

I work on Xcode and I have a simple function that opens a file using `open` in C.

```
 void mfs_workwith() {
  char *token, *temp_token;
  char *search = ".";
  temp_token = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(cc[1]));
  strcpy(temp_token, cc[1]);
  if ((token = strtok(temp_token, search)) == NULL) {
    printf("mfs_workwith command is only used with mfs type files e.g. example.mfs \n");
  } else if ((token = strtok(NULL, " \n\0")) == NULL) {
    printf("mfs_workwith command is only used with mfs type files e.g. example.mfs \n");
  } else if (strcmp(token, "mfs") == 0) {
    filename = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(cc[1]));
    strcpy(filename, cc[1]);
    if ((file_mfs = open(filename, O_RDWR)) == -1) {
      perror("open error");
    } else {
      printf("open successful \n");
    }
  }
}
```

The name of the file is stored in a global array and then copied into local buffers in order to tokenize and check if it has the right format (.mfs).

Then if everything is ok I make a fresh copy of the name of the file and call `open` with it.

My problem is that when I run my program in terminal it runs fine, prints `open successful` and then continues. But when I try to run it in Xcode it fails with this error:

```
No such file or directory
```

I am giving the input `file.mfs` which is the name of a file in the same directory.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Is it the path of the file you are trying to open? have you tried to give an absolute path? and also [don't cast the return value from `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I did try the absolute path and it works. So I guess my real problem is to open a relative path via xcode. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796943/open-method-opens-files-with-full-path-only-c wich answers my question.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem thanks to iharob's comment. It seems xcode has a hard time opening relative paths since it uses a different file while running the program. There is a relative discussion here:

[Open method opens files with full path only C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796943/open-method-opens-files-with-full-path-only-c)

thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
filename = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(cc[1]));
strcpy(filename, cc[1]);
```

is broken, it fails to allocate room for the string's terminator, so it causes buffer overflow and undefined behavior.

Also, you never need to scale by `sizeof (char)`, that's always 1. It should be:

```
filename = malloc(strlen(cc[1]) + 1);
strpcy(filename, cc[1]);
```

or, if you have it, just:

```
filename = strdup(cc[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but this does not seem to be my problem.
I added the code:
http://pastebin.com/CjZMVM26

in order to make sure there is a \0 at the end of my string but still terminal runs the program fine but xcode does not.