# How to load image via relative path in SFML using XCode IDE

Tags: c++, xcode, relative-path, sfml

As of right now, I am using full path to load a image via sf::Image. But I'm trying to use relative path, but it doesn't really work because the current working directory of the binary is at some weird directory. So I'm asking, how can I load an image using relative path via sf::Image::LoadFromFile(fileName)? I am trying to avoid absolute paths. I tried 'adding' the image files to the same directory as my source, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be great guys.

Answer (score 1):

I'm asuming you're using SFML 2 because I had the same issue with SFML 2, but not with 1.6.

[This topic on SFMLs site](http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4283) summed up the issue, with some solution. Apparently when SFML2 gets released as a framework we'll beable to link resources correctly again. Until then I'm still using absolute paths.

Comment: Actually I'm stil using SFML 1.6, thats weird

Comment: @user814628 Try changing [working directory setting.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396378/change-the-working-directory-in-xcode)