# freopen() doesn't work on mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am trying to run a code with freopen() on mac os,
but it doesn't print any output in the specified file.
although, it works perfectly on windows.
I am using the X-Code Editor and the input and the output files are in the same path as the cpp file

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(){
    freopen("input.in","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.out","w",stdout);

    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d\n",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start with checking the return value to see if opening succeeded. If you're running from within XCode, you need to set the project's working directory to the appropriate location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the working directory of your executable **is not** the directory where you have your `.cpp` files.

You may point to your files with absolute paths, ex. `/Users/omar/Documents/input.in`

or change the working directory from xcode settings (see [Change the working directory in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396378/change-the-working-directory-in-xcode) )

Answer (score -1):

I personally tried changing the working directory, but it still didn't work...
Later I find out that if you compile your c++ file using Terminal, there would be no trouble at all!

To compile c++ using Terminal, type in these commands:

1. `cd yourFileDirectory`
2. `g++ -o yourFileName yourFileName.cpp` (this will compile your code)
3. `./yourFileName` (and this will run the code successfully!)