# Can't open file using relative path in freopen() under OS X?

Tags: c

I'm learning to use `freopen()` to redirect stdin to a file.

I'm under `OS X 10.10` and I'm using Xcode to run my code.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    freopen("../data.in", "r", stdin);
    char a;
    scanf("%c", &a);
    fclose(stdin);
    printf("%c", a);
   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
I use `tree` command in terminal to show file structure and the output is

```
.
├── competition
│   └── main.c
├── competition.xcodeproj
│   ├── project.pbxproj
│   ├── project.xcworkspace
│   │   ├── contents.xcworkspacedata
│   │   ├── xcshareddata
│   │   │   └── competition.xccheckout
│   │   └── xcuserdata
│   │       └── yang.xcuserdatad
│   │           └── UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
│   └── xcuserdata
│       └── yang.xcuserdatad
│           ├── xcdebugger
│           │   └── Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
│           └── xcschemes
│               ├── competition.xcscheme
│               └── xcschememanagement.plist
├── data.in
└── makefile
```

I've also check the output of `freopen()`. The function returned `NULL`.

I got nothing while **I got correct output when I changed `"../data.in"` to absolute path.**

How can I fix it using relative paths?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this issue. Are you sure this is not a problem with the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a relative path, you must know what is the current directory of your running process.

See [`getcwd()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd).

If you are launching the program from a command line, the current directory is the same as the command line one. In command line (`sh`, `bash`...) the command `pwd` will tell you where you are.

If you launch the program from a debugger, the debugger will choose the program starting directory, this should be an option of your debugger.

Comment: Just like you said, Xcode changes the debug working directory to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-/Build/Products/Debug`. Customizing the working directory makes everything work correctly.

Comment: You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396378/change-the-working-directory-in-xcode for changing working directory

Answer (score 3):

The relative path is unrelated to where the program source live. It's actually relative to "current working directory" (basically, type `pwd` in your shell window to see what your working directory is, then run the program, if there's a file in `../data.in`, it will work, otherwise you'll probably get all sorts of weird errors).

You should also check the return value from `freopen`, if it returns NULL, an error occurred and you should probably deal with that.

Comment: I've edited the question and added my project structure. I've tried to use `pwd` to help me work it out but in vain. I don't think there's anything wrong with the path because the file `data.in` does exist in the parent directory of `main.c`. Could you please give me any hint?

Comment: Well, I've figured it out. It is the working directory that set by `Xcode` that lead to the issue. Just like @purplepsycho mentioned. In Xcode the default debug working directory is `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-/Build/Products/Debug`. After I customized the working directory, everything worked fine.