# Where are text files in my Xcode project?

Tags: c, xcode, file-pointer

I've created a simple program to write in a text file, and it seems as if it works. I just cannot find where to locate the text file it created in my Xcode project.

```
    FILE *fptr;

    fptr= fopen("testawesome.txt", "w");
    
    fputs("I love programming!", fptr);
    
    fclose(fptr);
    
    return(0);
}
```

I believe the code is fine, I just can't find exactly where the text file is. When I search in finder for `testawesome.txt`, it just references my project and not the text I want it to create.

Comment: You haven't tested that the file was opened successfully; you should ***always*** do that.

Comment: See [Change the working directory in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396378/change-the-working-directory-in-xcode)